# Can't use DB::table expression in my Facade Class - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, facade

Can't use DB::table in my class. I get a handleShutdown.
Please can some one tell me why. 
I'm spending hours on this and I might be going mad.

Follow below the code:

app/acl/Acl.php

> ```
> namespace AccessControl;
>
> class Acl 
> {
>
>     public function hasPermission($group_id, $module_name, $permission_type) {
>
>       $result = DB::table('permission')->get();
>       return $result;
>     }
> }
> ```

app/acl/AclFacade.php

> ```
> namespace AccessControl\Facades;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
>
> class Acl extends Facade {
>
>     protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'acl'; }
>
> }
> ```

app/acl/AclServiceProvider

> ```
> namespace AccessControl;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
>
>
> class AclServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
>
>     public function register()
>     {
>         // Register 'acl' instance container to our acl object
>         $this->app['acl'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
>         {
>             return new Acl;
>         });
>
>         // Shortcut so developers don't need to add an Alias in app/config/app.php
>         $this->app->booting(function()
>         {
>             $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
>             $loader->alias('Acl', 'AccessControl\Facades\Acl');
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

app.php

> 'providers' => array(
>
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
>     'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
>     'AccessControl\AclServiceProvider',

composer.js

> ```
>       "psr-0": {
>           "App\\": "app/",
>           "App\\Acl\\": "app/acl",
>
> [...]
>       "classmap": [
>           "app/commands",
>           "app/acl",
> [...]
> ```

And i used the command

> Composer Dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell PHP it is in the root namespace:

```
$result = \DB::table('permission')->get();
```

Or use it in the top of your .php file:

```
use DB;
```

Comment: I used that. But i'm using the join expression and dont work.

Comment: I added a join, but I already fix it. 
thanks for the help. :)